# Unable to resize an UITableViewCell containing an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom table view cell. I have a UIView in the tableview cell that is shown only when the table is expanded. I toggle the height for table view cell each time on tap to show the UIView. I also need to detect clicks on some of the components of UIView.

->tablecell1

-->UIView1 height h1

->tablecell2

-->UIView2 height h2

The cell height of the cell should vary according to the size of UIView. Currently I am calling
`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for varying the height on cell click. However this doesn't work if the UIViews are of variable heights and the bigger view gets clipped.

Is there a better way of solving it?

Comment: Can you post your code? You should never call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` directly. You should call any of the reload methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW61

Comment: did you give fix height to your UIView as constrains in IB ?

Comment: you can easily achieve dynamic tableview cells with auto layout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension (since iOS8). You can find more information here: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: i'll try the adding constrains for cell sizing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so real quick `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` shall not be called by your controller.

The biggest problem I always run into when dynamically sizing cells is that that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called very early on in the table layout process, so essentially the height of each cell must be know prior to asking the tableview to layout. Anyway I am going to assume that you are using a custom table view cell and have placed a UIView inside there... If you haven't, do.

First: Throw a class function into the CustomTableViewCell called `heightNeededForTableViewCellWithView:(UIView *)view` and determine the height you would want, handle the condition where view is nil and what the `default` size shall be.

Second: Call this class function when `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called and since you own the datasource in your controller you can dynamically return the `heightNeededForTableViewCellWithView:viewAtRow` based off the view you would want to show for that row!

Third: When a user taps a cell, remember which index they tapped and call [tableView reloadData] which will call `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: will try that out. Seems more of a hack but it should work if I could guess the size of UIView based on my data.